# How do I put restrictions to an email type of input?

Tags: html, validation, email, input

My  element with type="email" has a `pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"`but the following were not included.

- email address should not begin with an integer
- email address should include ".com"

How do I include them on the pattern?

Comment: what do you mean by "restrict numbers in before the number"

Comment: e.g. 123_name@gmail.com - this should be invalid

Comment: so you should not be able to start an email with a number?

Comment: yes yes sorry about my explanation

Comment: I smell an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you ever want to reject perfectly valid email addresses?